# Как вернуть смартфон в «Online» для отладки приложений?

Tags: android-studio, android

Нажал запуск приложения и мой смартфон отображается как "Offline".
От чего это и как вернуть?

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1):

1. вынуть , воткнуть провод из смарта.
2. в cmd

```
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server
```

3. бывает проблема с дровами